# MotionLayout animation item doesn't work inside RecyclerView

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-motionlayout

How I can handle items animation made with `MotionLayout` inside `RecyclerView` Because when I start [scrolling like here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_LwSTvcoI7r7jLLSDb1GcKhoDU9SGS5t/view) everything becomes very messy.

*I Know how `RecyclerView` works, but I try a lot to reset or control the `MotionLayout` Animate but It didn't work all the time and is still messy*

adapter code

```java
class StoryViewHolder(private val mainView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mainView){

    private var root: MotionLayout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.motion_root)
    private var deleteBtn: RelativeLayout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn)
    private var editBtn: RelativeLayout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.edit_btn)
    private var storyImage: RoundedImageView = mainView.findViewById(R.id.story_image)
    private var storyTitleTv: TextView = mainView.findViewById(R.id.story_title_tv)
    private var storyAuthorTv: TextView = mainView.findViewById(R.id.story_author_tv)
    private var tagsLL: LinearLayout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.tags_ll)
    private var favouriteImg: ImageView = mainView.findViewById(R.id.favourite_img)

    lateinit var storyListener: StoryViewListener

    private lateinit var story: Story

    interface StoryViewListener {
        fun onDelete(story: Story, position: Int)
    }

    init {
        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener {
            storyListener.onDelete(story, adapterPosition)
        }

        editBtn.setOnClickListener {
        }

        storyImage.setOnClickListener {

        }
    }

    fun set(story: Story) {
        this.story = story
        Glide
            .with(mainView.context)
            .load(story.image)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(storyImage)

        storyTitleTv.text = story.title
        storyAuthorTv.text = "" 
        addTags(story.tags)

    }

    private fun addTags(tags: String) {
        tagsLL.removeAllViews()
        tags.split(",").forEach {
            val view =
                LayoutInflater.from(mainView.context).inflate(R.layout.view_tag, null, false)
            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tag).text = it
            tagsLL.addView(view)
        }
    }

    fun setStart() {
        root.transitionToStart()
    }

    fun setEnd() {
        root.transitionToEnd()
    }
}
```

ViewHolder code

```java
class StoryViewHolder(private val mainView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mainView){

    private var root: MotionLayout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.motion_root)
    private var deleteBtn: RelativeLayout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn)
    private var editBtn: RelativeLayout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.edit_btn)
    private var storyImage: RoundedImageView = mainView.findViewById(R.id.story_image)
    private var storyTitleTv: TextView = mainView.findViewById(R.id.story_title_tv)
    private var storyAuthorTv: TextView = mainView.findViewById(R.id.story_author_tv)
    private var tagsLL: LinearLayout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.tags_ll)
    private var favouriteImg: ImageView = mainView.findViewById(R.id.favourite_img)

    lateinit var storyListener: StoryViewListener

    private lateinit var story: Story

    interface StoryViewListener {
        fun onDelete(story: Story, position: Int)
    }

    init {
        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener {
            storyListener.onDelete(story, adapterPosition)
        }

        editBtn.setOnClickListener {
        }

        storyImage.setOnClickListener {

        }
    }

    fun set(story: Story) {
        this.story = story
        Glide
            .with(mainView.context)
            .load(story.image)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(storyImage)

        storyTitleTv.text = story.title
        storyAuthorTv.text = ""
        addTags(story.tags)

    }

    private fun addTags(tags: String) {
        tagsLL.removeAllViews()
        tags.split(",").forEach {
            val view =
                LayoutInflater.from(mainView.context).inflate(R.layout.view_tag, null, false)
            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tag).text = it
            tagsLL.addView(view)
        }
    }

    fun setStart() {
        root.transitionToStart()
    }

    fun setEnd() {
        root.transitionToEnd()
    }
}
```

MotionLayout Animation code

```xml
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="300">
        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="40"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/horizontalScrollView" />
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="100"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/horizontalScrollView" />

            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="50"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/edit_btn" />
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="1"
                motion:framePosition="100"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/edit_btn" />
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="50"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/delete_btn" />
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="1"
                motion:framePosition="100"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/delete_btn" />
        </KeyFrameSet>
        <OnClick motion:targetId="@+id/story_image" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start"></ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/story_image"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/story_image"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/story_image"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/story_image"
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/favourite_img"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/story_image" />


        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/story_title_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/story_author_tv"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/story_image"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/story_image"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/story_image" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/story_author_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/story_image"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/story_image"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/story_image"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/story_title_tv" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/story_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:riv_corner_radius="10dp" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/story_image" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edit_btn"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/story_image" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/edit_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/delete_btn"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/story_image" />


    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem:
I had to control the `MotionLayout` animation **completely** from the `Adapter` inside `onBindViewHolder(..)` not from the `MotionScene`
, So I deleted `<OnClick motion:targetId="@+id/story_image" />` from the scene file `xml\motion_scene`   ,and I changed the adapter code.

here's the short code:

```
val START_MODE = 0
val END_MODE = 1

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: StoryViewHolder, position: Int) {
   val model = modelsList[position]

   if (model.animeMode == START_MODE)
      holder.motionLayout.transitionToStart()
   else
      holder.motionLayout.transitionToEnd()

   holder.storyImage.setOnClickListener {
       if (models.get(holder.adapterPosition).animeMode == StoryModel.START_MODE) {
           models.get(holder.adapterPosition).animeMode = StoryModel.END_MODE
           holder.motionLayout.transitionToEnd()
       } else {
           models.get(holder.adapterPosition).animeMode = StoryModel.START_MODE
           holder.motionLayoutRoot.transitionToStart()
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [RecyclerView.ItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator) for `recyclerView` animations. See [recycerView.setItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#setItemAnimator(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator)) method.  It's wrong to animate `ViewHolder` views directly into adapter because `recyclerView` reuse views. While you scroll `recyclerView` bind old views to new items, but `recyclerview` doesn't know that old views are in process of animation, that's why it becomes messy.

Here is [good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imsr8NrIAMs) which explains how `recyclerView` and `ItemAnimator` works.
Here is [nice tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/recyclerview-item-change-animations-ebe2383bb481) with custom `ItemAnimator` implementation.